# Want the variable values on the same page after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have three variables, the first variable gets the first value and another two will get the  second value.

```
 $ids   = $_GET['abc'];
 $minprice  = $_GET['minprice'];  
 $maxprice  = $_GET['maxprice'];
```

Basically i want the values of the varialbes on page after page refresh.

Sorry for the english..

Comment: and what code have you tried?

Comment: You should look into sessions and session variables.

Answer (score 0):

if you want that variable to stay after refresh then use this way which i use always :-

```
<?php
session_start();
$ids = $_GET['abc'];
$ids = $_SESSION['abc'];

echo $_SESSION['abc'];
?>
```

And if you want them to unset use :-

```
unset($_SESSION['abc'];
```

Comment: Basically i am working on the php filter for products and their using javascript or ajax.. so i am getting each and every time value change. so is it possible with this code?

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`localStorage` or `sessionStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) easily.
`localStorage.ids=$ids`

Comment: Basically i am working on the php filter for products and their using javascript or ajax.. so i am getting each and every time value change. so is it possible with this code?

Comment: yeah you can use one of them depending on the requirement. If you need to keep them for next session as well , then you need to use localStogage otherwise per session.

Comment: I am unable to store variable values after page refresh